Rails Active Record Relations: merge different active record relations with the same classname
Suppose I have the following models (among others)
class Child < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent1, class_name: "Parent"
    belongs_to :parent2, class_name: "Parent"
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :children
end

I want to chain active record relations using .merge() (or .or()) to minimize # sql queries, and also to keep query concerns reusable & separate, for scalability of a complex data model. I know how to do this for a single parent.
Child.where(**child_criteria).joins(:parent1).merge(ParentActiveRecordRelation)

This will do a
... INNER JOIN "parents" ON "parents"."id" = "children"."parent1_id" WHERE ... ["parents" attribute criteria] ...

But now I am faced with building an active record relation where ParentActiveRecordRelation could apply to either :parent1 or :parent2. Worse yet, what if I had a Parent1ActiveRecordRelation that applied to :parent1 and a Parent2ActiveRecordRelation that applied to :parent2?
I tried chaining two separate merges with an or,
Child.where(**child_criteria).joins(:parent1).merge(Parent1ActiveRecordRelation).or(Child.where(**child_criteria).joins(:parent2).merge(Parent2ActiveRecordRelation))

but rails returns
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]


The code in your example doesn't actually work because the plural of child is children.

@max I've edited syntactical details. I've tested that the code above works as is now written.

Update: My current workaround is to add a redundant association between the child and the parent's parent, which in my case is a common association, so I can chain associations skipping over parent1 and parent2, and I wrote some manual SQL to handle the parent1 and parent2 cases. But the question still remains: how can we specify a custom column name when merging an active record relation?
